# Vim colorscheme changes terminal after exit

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu on the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

in my .vimrc:

```
set term=xterm-256color
colorscheme morning
```

in my .bashrc:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

the term command in my .vimrc is necessary for `home` and `end` keys to work, and the term command in my .bashrc is necessary to fix [this same issue](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues/149).

**The problem is the following:**

When I exit vim, my terminal colors now match the vim colorscheme!
What is going on, and how do I fix this?

[image]

I'm unsure if this is relevant, but my vim *was working with these settings* prior to the latest Windows 10 update. The update corrupted my WSL and I had to re-enable WSL and delete and reinstall Ubuntu.

**Edit:** I've confirmed that I have the same issue even with an empty .vimrc and .bashrc.

Comment: Not to be rude, but why not install the pure Linux?

Comment: 1.) I can't just dual-boot my work machine, and 2.) the WSL is faster than a VM

Comment: same issue, unfortunately. My current workaround is running ubuntu.exe and then opening a gnome-terminal, which DOES work correctly